# Why is [ngClass] directive shown with brackets

Tags: angular

As I understand, directives are used without brackets on DOM elements. However, [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) `ngClass` is shown with brackets:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directives are used without brackets, but if there's a binding inside directive class with the same name as a directive, it should be wrapped in brackets. This happens with `ngClass` directive. Here is the relevant source code from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts#L62):

```
@Directive({selector: '[ngClass]'})
export class NgClass implements DoCheck {
     ...

  @Input('class')
  set klass(v: string) {
      ...
  }

  @Input()
  set ngClass(v: string|string[]|Set<string>|{[klass: string]: any}) {
```

So we can see that there's `ngClass` input defined. Basically, the original code can be rewritten like this to make it clear:

```
<some-element ngClass [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

Or like this using `class` input binding:

```
<some-element ngClass [class]="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [Property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding)

```
<some-element [ngClass]="expression">...</some-element>
```

tells angular to *evaluate* the expression and bind to it.

```
<some-element ngClass="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

Here you are just setting a string literal. With direct string literal both work fine but not with a variable or an expression.

**Case where this would matter:**

If you have a class object defined in component

```
this.class = {this.class1: this.isClass1,this.class2:isCass2}
```

and set it in your html.

```
[ngClass]="class"
```

or you could have an expression like a ternary operation to verify if you need to have a class.

```
[ngClass]="isClass1?Class1:Class2"
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, but `ngClass` is not a property, it's a directive

Comment: check the link..property binding applies to directives as well

Comment: yeah, thanks, I've figured out [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42067703/2545680) myself, but I'll upvote since you gave me an insight I was missing :)

Comment: I see.. didnt think of digging into the source code :)